# Mapping Tables in Access Without ID

Tags: vba, ms-access

If I have multiple tables all from the same XML source, but one of those tables has a number of different items in one column, and no column specifying who those items belong to, while another table has a list of each person and an ID for each person is it possible to link the two tables, or would the person ID or name need to be present in the items table?

Comment: How do you know which items belong to which person?

Comment: @Andy I imagine I don't, and that there is no way for me to know that, but I just wanted to confirm this with someone else to make sure I wasn't missing some kind of magic that Access has to offer.  It would be impossible unless there was a column in the item table specifying that, right?

Comment: If you don't know then Access won't. No, no magic I'm afraid. Yes, you need something in the table that relates it to the other table.

Comment: You would need to have something that identifies a record in the Items table to the record from the person table.  Usually that is some sort of ID number, but there are other ways. Would have to see your data.

Comment: @Andy I should mention that looking through the XML file I can see which belong to which customer, but the issue is that this is only because there are 'blocks' of person item data for each person.  Since everything is aggregated in Access this block structure is not available to help me.  Is that reasonable?

Comment: Alan has suggested you post some data.

Comment: "`Reverse engineering` is the process of discovering the technological principles of a human made device, object or system through analysis of its structure, function and operation." I don't think that applies here. And I don't see how `Schema` fits in either.

Comment: @Doug My apologies, that was a complete accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar situation, I made a VBA routine that would crawl the database in search of whatever I entered.

Systematically following the few clues I had yielded a lot of information.  The routine itself was just a few hundred lines of code.

```
Open Database
Get all Tables 
For Each Table
   Get all Fields
   For Each Field
       If Field type is text ... and
       If Field size is not TOO Long ...
           Search for string
           If found, write to a results bucket
   Next
Next
```

So my answer is Yes, it can be done.  But,

1. There is painstaking work to get it running (depends really on your VBA expertise)
2. The more you know about your real-world connections, the better you can exploit the tool.